# How can I send remote commands to an AppServer programmatically?

Tags: java, openedge

I need to send commands (query, start, stop) to a remote OpenEdge AppServer. This will be running on OpenEdge 11.3.

As far as I can tell, these are the options:

- OpenEdge Management. This is a webapp that can be accessed over HTTP(S). All that's required is a web browser. Unfortunately, it's designed for interactive use - trying to control it programmatically would be crazy.
- The `asbman` command-line utility. This is a batch file that calls into a Java command-line application, and allows management of both local and remote AppServers. While this is pretty much exactly what I need, it comes with a heavy cost: it seems that the only way to use it is to install OE, which is not exactly lightweight at over 500 MB. That includes everything needed to *run* the AppServers, while I only need to be able to send commands to an already running remote server.

  I should note that this only takes in the password interactively, though that can be worked around (redirecting STDIN is trivial).

  - If I could extract that Java application (`com.progress.ubroker.tools.UBCmdClient`, `progress.jar`), that would be fine. However, it calls into at least one native library (`jutil.dll`), and they use a custom launcher (`jvmStart.exe`).

    Trying to launch it through the standard Java launcher (`java.exe`) results in errors loading the native library (`Expecting an absolute path of the library: null\bin\jutil.dll`). I'm working on extracting `jvmStart.exe` too, but there seems to be many dependencies.

    I cannot find any documentation on this.
- `asbman` eventually ends up communicating with the AdminServer and possibly AppServers through a protocol Progress apparently calls "Chimera". Unfortunately, I can't seem to find documentation anywhere.

Is there anything I missed? Does anyone know of a method, preferably but not necessarily documented (at this point, as long as it works, ties to the specific OE version is fine for now), to remotely and programmatically send queries and commands to an AppServer without installing the entire suite? I just can't believe no-one ever thought that might be a useful thing to have.

Comment: Addendum: We have already tried contacting Progress, but they have been rather useless with their responses (suggesting the use of the webapp, asking why we need to "develop our own tool" [we're not! we want to *call* an existing one if possible, just without a human clicking through it!] and told us to "extract the progress.jar file and you can find the class" [then what? what on earth are we supposed to do with a lone compiled class file?]). I'm hoping this is currently just a miscommunication (or clueless agent) and not an indication of actual absence of other options.

Comment: Have you considered scripting using some kind of remote shell? I'm not that familiar with remote shelling on Windows but it might be possible?

Comment: @Jensd I did think about it at one point - PowerShell remoting and PsExec were both options. That is something we may still decide to do - I actually completely forgot about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have bad news for you.

There is no stand-alone asbman and none of what you are looking for is documented.

I expect that you are going to have to bite the bullet and install OE.  You could probably trim an awful lot of fluff out of the install either through trial and error or by careful monitoring of which files are actually used.  Personally, I've never found that sort of thing to be worth much effort.  Disk is cheap.

None the less if you do find a solution I'd be interested.

Comment: Ah. That's a pity. Thanks for the response. It's not so much the size (as you say, disk is cheap), but the requirement for installation: for what we are currently trying to do, we want to minimise unnecessary changes to the system. IIRC the simple act of installing OE adds startup entries, etc., that will have to be disabled. Still, if this is the only way then I guess we'll just have to bite the bullet.

Comment: True on Windows.  Linux is a whole lot easier when it comes to simple installs and managing multiple versions.

Answer (score 2):

My name is Mei Swank.  I am a Progress OpenEdge Technical Support Manager and am not happy to hear your experience with our team on this topic was not positive.  We are working to address this.

To answer your question whether there is a way to remotely manage an Appserver without installing the product, there are no means to run an AppServer admin command from one machine against a remote AppServer running on another machine without installing OpenEdge.

If your goal is to remotely control an AppServer running on another windows machine without installing OpenEdge product on the machine, there could be two options:

1. Windows remote shell scripting using Power Shell, just like you have investigated.
2. Use OpenEdge Management product, and set up the AppServer management script as a job to run on scheduled basis. OpenEdge Management can be installed on any machine and web console can be used in the browser to remotely manage jobs.

If you are interested in reducing install footprint, instead of installing an AppServer license, install a Name server free deployment component product, to remotely manage AppServer. This approach will reduce install foot print from 500 Meg to about 179 Meg. This deployment component is a free product that can be downloaded from ESD.

We have also documented these options in a knowledgebase article that can be reference here.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000056238

Thank you and let me know whether you have additional questions.

Mei

Comment: Thank you for the answer. At this point, we have decided to go ahead and use the full AppServer licence.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a look into this and will get back to you if I find something/an answer.

Not that it helps you in 11.3/4 and the "classic" AppServer but there will definitely be a REST API to the Pacific AppServer (the new AppServer announced at Exchange: http://media.progress.com/exchange/2014/slides/track1_living-with-pacific-application-server-for-openedge.pdf).

If I find anything out about programmatically controlling earlier releases, I will let you know.

Comment: Hm. Thanks for looking into it. It's nice to know something more formal is planned for the future, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
**strong text**
Hi,

i run the commands on windows to query or preform action on an appserver vis batch, from a remote desktop i use psexec \\remoteserver c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe to access remote command line on server
after that have some batches to query/stop/start/kill appserver

hope this will bring u closer to what u need , I am working on same concept to manage appserver/db/name server from html as progress ver. 9.1E running on win2008 does not support "Progress Explorer Tool"

regards 

Emad

#####################################################
rem appserver 
@echo off
SET TYP=type
SET APS=asb_xxx_%TYP%
set prt=20931
set ENV=PROD
set DLC=D:\PROGRESS\OpenEdge\102B\DLC

if (%1) == () %DLC%\bin\asbman -port %prt% -i %APS%_%ENV% -q
if (%1) == (q) %DLC%\bin\asbman -port %prt% -i %APS%_%ENV% -%1
if (%1) == (stop)  %DLC%\bin\asbman -port %prt% -i %APS%_%ENV% -%1
if (%1) == (start) %DLC%\bin\asbman -port %prt% -i %APS%_%ENV% -%1
if (%1) == (t)  %DLC%\bin\asbman -port %prt% -i %APS%_%ENV% -trim %2
if (%1) == (a)  %DLC%\bin\asbman -port %prt% -i %APS%_%ENV% -s %2
if (%1) == (kill) %DLC%\bin\asbman -port %prt% -i %APS%_%ENV% -%1

#####################################################

rem name server 
@echo off
:loop
color 1B
cls
SET ATP=asb_0165_autopro
SET EDI=asb_0165_edi
SET SRS=asb_0165_srs
SET INV=asb_0165_inv
SET JIT=asb_0165_jit
SET PLN=asb_0165_plan
SET SNC=asb_0165_sonic
SET ENV=PROD
SET SITE=0165
SET /A counter=%counter%+1
if %counter%==10 GOTO end:
echo.
echo.
echo======================================================================
echo                  AppServers For the %SITE%-%ENV% environment
echo======================================================================
echo.
title                 AppServers For the %SITE%-%ENV% environment

for /F "tokens=1-10" %%i in ('D:\PROGRESS\OpenEdge\102B\DLC\bin\nsman.bat -port 20931 -name NS1 -q') do (
if /I "%%j" equ "AS.%ATP%_%ENV%" ( @echo %%j      RUNS ON   %%k )

)



for /F "tokens=1-10" %%i in ('D:\PROGRESS\OpenEdge\102B\DLC\bin\nsman.bat -port 20931 -name NS1 -q') do (
if /I "%%j" equ "AS.%EDI%_%ENV%" ( @echo %%j          RUNS ON   %%k )

)


for /F "tokens=1-10" %%i in ('D:\PROGRESS\OpenEdge\102B\DLC\bin\nsman.bat -port 20931 -name NS1 -q') do (
if /I "%%j" equ "AS.%SRS%_%ENV%" ( @echo %%j          RUNS ON   %%k )

)

for /F "tokens=1-10" %%i in ('D:\PROGRESS\OpenEdge\102B\DLC\bin\nsman.bat -port 20931 -name NS1 -q') do (
if /I "%%j" equ "AS.%INV%_%ENV%" ( @echo %%j          RUNS ON   %%k )

)


for /F "tokens=1-10" %%i in ('D:\PROGRESS\OpenEdge\102B\DLC\bin\nsman.bat -port 20931 -name NS1 -q') do (
if /I "%%j" equ "AS.%JIT%_%ENV%" ( @echo %%j          RUNS ON   %%k )

)


for /F "tokens=1-10" %%i in ('D:\PROGRESS\OpenEdge\102B\DLC\bin\nsman.bat -port 20931 -name NS1 -q') do (
if /I "%%j" equ "AS.%PLN%_%ENV%" ( @echo %%j         RUNS ON   %%k )

)

for /F "tokens=1-10" %%i in ('D:\PROGRESS\OpenEdge\102B\DLC\bin\nsman.bat -port 20931 -name NS1 -q') do (
if /I "%%j" equ "AS.%SNC%_%ENV%" ( @echo %%j        RUNS ON   %%k )

)

    enter code here

sleep 3

goto loop
:end
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
just for the fun of it i ran this command from my laptop (without any progress installation`enter code here` on my laptop):



C:\WINDOWS\system32>psexec \\a-690m111 r:\AproApp\0165\prod\scripts\atp.cmd


PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Starting r:\AproApp\0165\prod\scripts\atp.cmd on a-690m111...

OpenEdge Release 10.2B08 as of Tue Nov 12 19:06:41 EST 2013


Connecting to Progress AdminServer using rmi://localhost:20931/Chimera (8280)
Searching for asb_0165_autopro_PROD (8288)
Connecting to asb_0165_autopro_PROD  (8276)

Broker-Name                    : asb_0165_autopro_PROD
Betriebsmodus                  : Stateless
Broker-Status                  :  ACTIVE 
Broker-Anschluss               : 15201
Broker-PID                     : 6104
Aktive Server                  : 10
Ausgelastete Server            : 0
Gesperrte Server               : 0
Verfügbare Server              : 10
Aktive Clients (jetzt, Spitze) : (0, 2)
Client-Warteschl. (jetzt, max) : (0, 0)
Summe der Anfragen             : 26
Anf-Wartezeit (max, durchschn) : (0 ms, 0 ms)
Anf-Dauer (max, durchschn.)    : (3740 ms, 299 ms)

PID   Zustand   Port  nAnf   nAempf nSent  Gestartet        Letzte ؤnderung  
05644 AVAILABLE 15210 000006 000006 000006 21.12.2014 21:44 21.12.2014 21:48 
05544 AVAILABLE 15211 000003 000003 000003 21.12.2014 21:44 21.12.2014 21:49 
05396 AVAILABLE 15212 000002 000002 000005 21.12.2014 21:44 21.12.2014 21:48 
05400 AVAILABLE 15213 000002 000002 000012 21.12.2014 21:44 21.12.2014 21:48 
02540 AVAILABLE 15214 000002 000003 000003 21.12.2014 21:44 21.12.2014 21:48 
06052 AVAILABLE 15215 000003 000003 000004 21.12.2014 21:44 21.12.2014 21:49 
05296 AVAILABLE 15216 000002 000003 000003 21.12.2014 21:44 21.12.2014 21:48 
06088 AVAILABLE 15217 000002 000002 000002 21.12.2014 21:44 21.12.2014 21:48 
06184 AVAILABLE 15218 000002 000002 000002 21.12.2014 21:44 21.12.2014 21:48 
06216 AVAILABLE 15219 000002 000002 000002 21.12.2014 21:44 21.12.2014 21:49 



r:\AproApp\0165\prod\scripts\atp.cmd exited on a-690m111 with error code 0.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on somewhat recent version of OpenEdge Explorer (or Management) (11.0+) there is a fairly wide set of REST APIs you can use via curl or something similar that requires virtually zero footprint.

Fetch complete list of resources with basic status

curl -u admin:admin -u http://localhost:9090/oem/resources

Fetch status of appserver (using URL fetched from above)

curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:9090/oem/containers/localhost/AppServer/serers/localhost:resource.openedge.appserver.asbroker1

Comment: Is this method commented anywhere or is it a hack? Is it possible to query this way?

Answer (score 0):

Start an appserver:

curl -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"running": true}' http://localhost:9090/oem/containers/localhost/AppServer/serers/localhost:resource.openedge.appserver.asbroker1

stop an appserver:

curl -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"running": false}' http://localhost:9090/oem/containers/localhost/AppServer/serers/localhost:resource.openedge.appserver.asbroker1